# ExtJS hbox - combo trigger

Tags: extjs, combobox, panel, hbox

i have the hbox layout as below

```
 window
 --------------------------
| panel
| Form 
| hbox
|   row 1  combo1 combo2
| form
|  hbox
|   row 2  combo1 combo2
|
|
 --------------------------
```

The row 2 is added dynamically on clicking a button. Same code is executed to add row 1 and row 2 to hbox. When i click on combo1 in row#1 the roe#2 combo gets clicked.

Any idea why this happens and any suggestion on how i can achieve the behaviour of clicking combo of particular row displays its store?

Comment: post some code & make sure you haven't specified same id to combo

Comment: i have same id for the combos. I need the same set of components to be added on click of a button. So same id will be there are combo for all rows of hbox. Will this be a problem? If yes, is there any way to override this?

Comment: try using `itemId` property of form field. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox-cfg-itemId. refer : http://softdevbuilttolast.wordpress.com/2012/06/20/extjs-avoid-using-the-id-property-unless-you-have-to/

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-232279.html?s=41d2d8d57e1dc785fb8a3cb113f6dd9d

Comment: Thanks MMT.. itemId for components under form works.. :-)

can you post your itemId comment as answer. So that it will be userful for others too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `itemId` property of form field.

refer [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox-cfg-itemId)  and [extjs-avoid-using-the-id-property](http://softdevbuilttolast.wordpress.com/2012/06/20/extjs-avoid-using-the-id-property-unless-you-have-to/)